# How to synchronized data in different database?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have four database(ALD,ASO,PAD,STF) each database having table vendors. All database vendors having same schema but data are vary from database to database.so my problem is i need to synchronized data only vendors table in all of four database.

please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For getting distinct data from all database table, I have used Union of all Tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM [ALD].[dbo].[Vendors] 
union
SELECT *
FROM [ASO].[dbo].[Vendors] 
union 
SELECT *
FROM [PAD].[dbo].[Vendors] 
union 
SELECT *
FROM [STF].[dbo].[Vendors]
```